# CSS - Place new DIVs on top of old DIVs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use "vertical-align: bottom;" to have DIVs go from the bottom of the wrapper/parent DIV to the top. The only problem is that I would like the first DIVs to be displayed at the bottom, NOT at the top like they usually are by default. This is only because I always want the bottom row to be full by having the first ones entered at the very bottom.

The order of the DIVs are not actually essential but I really want the very bottom "row" to be completely filled with the top row the only one which sometimes will only have 1 or 2 boxes on top for example. By adding new boxes on the top rather than at the bottom it would result in the layout I've described. I hope that makes sense.

Also the code I have added below shows gaps in between each "column" which I have been trying to remove. It might not matter if I have to change all the code to fix the first problem but if anyone knows why this is and lets me know, that would be great :)

Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

```css
div.wrapper {
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: bottom; 
 height: 500px;
 width: 640px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}
div.wrapper div {
 width: 200px; 
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
div.wrapper div p {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div style="background-color: #7E7ECC;">
  <p>1</p>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color: #FFA347;">
  <p>2</p>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color: #80E680;">
  <p>3</p>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color: #FF99C2;">
  <p>4</p>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color: #A6DBEE;">
  <p>5</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I want to create:

[image]

This would also be acceptable:
[image]

Comment: can't you change the order manually or you cannot change html?

Comment: It's not an issue with the order really, I just want the bottom "row" to be completely full and for the top row to have less which is the effect you get when new ones are placed on top if that makes sense

Comment: Otherwise when I stylize it in the future, the design is going to look very odd.

Comment: @1l13v I've added a new image to show another example of what the result could look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with CSS3 flexbox layout. `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` is the key property here as it allows the items to wrap in opposite direction of the `flex-direction: row`

`align-content: flex-start` is used instead of `*-end` since the wrap order was reversed.

```css
div.wrapper {
  /* Added Properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;  
  align-content: flex-start;
  /* ^ Added Properties */
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 150px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 640px;
}
div.wrapper div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.wrapper div p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: #7E7ECC;">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #FFA347;">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #80E680;">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #FF99C2;">
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #A6DBEE;">
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot! I've never seen those properties before and it even fixed the gap issue. I usually hate working with table-cell so really happy this exists. Thanks again :D

Comment: Haha :) Welcome! Make sure you check out flexbox awesomeness: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: I'm looking into it right now! It's made me realize how much I don't know about CSS3 <3

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem adding flex layout to wrapper and display items in row, which you want to reverse it to get the stacking effect. See the css below:

```
div.wrapper {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: bottom; 
    height: 500px;
    width: 640px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: flex; /* added */
    flex-direction: row; /* added */
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; /* added */
    align-content: flex-start; /* added */
}
div.wrapper div {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;  
}

div.wrapper div p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xgmdkpb8/7/)